# html forms download file django

Tags: html, django, file

I am stuck with this issue in Django: I want to download a file already existing on my server through a html form. The file to be downloaded is served through a function in views. My problem is with  html form and passing the file name  to view. How can I pass the name of the file from form toward view without having to select the file?

```
In html I have: 

# 'content' keeps the name of the file to be downloaded
    {% block content %}
{{content}}
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file"  name="file"/>
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Download File" />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

{% endblock %}
```

When I select the file and press submit button, it works but I need a different behavior: the name of the file containing results (downloadable file) to be passed to views into a  variable. The views will then serve it.

```
The view which handled the downloadable file:
def forecast(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        #handle_download_file(request.FILES['file'], str(request.FILES['file']))
        print('request.method este: ',request.method)

        RESULTS_filename = 'frcst_'+ str(request.FILES['file'])
        #download('GET', RESULTS_filename)
        file_path = os.path.join(os.path.relpath('forecast/'), RESULTS_filename)
        print (file_path)
        print(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
        with open(file_path,'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
            response['content-disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+RESULTS_filename
            print(response)
            return response
    HttpResponseRedirect('/forecast/')
    return render(request,'result_links.html',{'content':'frcst_history.csv'})
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a an `<input type="file">` for this but just a normal text input field, or better a `<select>` field where you prepopulate with the possible files the user can download. File input fields are meant for **uploading**, not **downloading** files.

Comment: I need to pass 'POST' method into view, in order  to handle the  file. Not sure if with select I can do this. With normal text input field how can I pre-populate the filename? Could you please give me a simple example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your create a form with a [`ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) and populate the field with the list of files, then in your template you just render that field `{{ form.file }}` which will be a `<select>`. Or is there only one file your user can download?

Comment: What are all those commented-out functions for? `handle_download_file()` and `download()`? Are you trying to actually *upload* anything? Or are you really just wanting to *download* a file? Please clarify. To download a file, you would usually use a `GET` verb, that's what GET is for. Not sure why you want to `POST` in order to GET a file?

Comment: The functions commented out is what I previously tried and didn't succeed. I am trying to use 'POST' instead of 'GET' because at everything which I tried with GET I received strange errors from django when passing the downloadable file name between html form and view. What I am actually trying to achieve is: 1) Upload a file to the server through view (done); 2) process the file and generate a new results file. The results file has the name: ''prefix_" + uploaded file name  (done). 3) Present a new html with a button to download the results file through a view. (Not working!)

Comment: Comment to my latest comment: Step 3) works only if I use ''POST" method and a html page with "input type="file"  button but in this case the user has to select the results file to be downloaded which is not what I need. I want the user to click a button (or a link) and the results file to be downloaded without asking the user to select it.